# Insert data to SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to use WPF to create a database, and insert data into the table.

I use a button to insert 4 different data into the table,
it works fine, but I can only insert "one" data in the table, 
no matter how many times I press the button.

Here's my code :

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=imageDB.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE image_table (id integer, name varchar(100), location varchar(500), appendix varchar(500));";
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string key = nowKey.ToString();
        string name = dbNameBox.Text;
        string location = dbLocationBox.Text;
        string app1 = dbNotebox.Text;

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO image_table (id, name, location, appendix) VALUES ('" + nowKey.ToString() + "', '" + name + "', '" + location + "', '" + app1 + "');";

        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM image_table";

        sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
        {
            string data = sqlite_datareader.GetString(3);
            MessageBox.Show(data);
        }

        sqlite_conn.Close();
    }
```

I didn't use "autoincrement" keyword here, neither nor "primary key".
I've tried move

```
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=imageDB.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
```

out of the function, but it still doesn't work.

Please give me advice! Really Appreciate
Thanks in advance!

Comment: on every click you are creating a table from scratch. Shouldn't you be creating the table once and then inserting the data in the same table afterwards? So what is happening is when you click on button, your table is created again overwriting what was already there.

Comment: WPF is responsible for *rendering and interactivity* behavior _only_. Everything in your event handler is plain old c#.

Comment: Yes, and I use WPF in other section in my program, this is only the section which made me really confused and stock me.

Answer (score 0):

on every click you are creating a table from scratch. you should be creating the table once (perhaps on program start or another button click, depending on your needs) and then inserting the data in the same table afterwards.

Currently what is happening is when you click on button, your table is created again overwriting what was already there.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new table every time.
To solve this problem, use: CREATE TABLE **IF NOT EXISTS**

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image_table (id integer, name varchar(100), location varchar(500), appendix varchar(500));";
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```